# Ember app kit and resource routes

Tags: ember.js, ember-app-kit

Am attempting to define nested resource within ember app kit. Is my file structure incorrect? When I add the nested resource, I get the following exception:

```
Error: Assertion Failed: The URL '/pages.index' did not match any routes in your application
```

By simply commenting out the function defining the nested "page" resource, the app loads correctly and displays the pages template.

Router code:

```
var Router = Ember.Router.extend(); 

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('component-test');
  this.route('helper-test');
  this.resource('pages', {path: '/pages'}
      // if this line is commented out, no error (index route is not called though)
      , function() { this.resource('page', {path: ':page_id'}); }
    );
});

export default Router;
```

File structure is thus:

```
$ ls -R
component-test.js   helper-test.js      pages
component_test.js   index.js        pages.js

./pages:
index.js    page.js
```

Pages route:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({

  model: function() {
    return [{title: "One", _id: "one"}, {title: "Two", _id: "two"}];
    //this.store.find('page');
  }

});
```

pages/index route:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.modelFor('page');
  }
});
```

The es6 generated module for the pages/index route looks like this:

```
define("appkit/routes/pages/index", 
  ["exports"],
  function(__exports__) {
    "use strict";
    __exports__["default"] = Ember.Route.extend({
      model: function() {
        return this.modelFor('page');
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: what was your solution?

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

Do you have your pages index route named "index.js" in a pages folder?

Ember App Kit looks up files by folder structure. So the pages index route should be found at "app/routes/pages/index.js".

Here is a repo with this code https://github.com/kiwiupover/for_eric

The Router

```
var Router = Ember.Router.extend(); 

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('component-test');
  this.route('helper-test');
  this.resource('pages', function() {
    this.route('new');
  });
});

export default Router;
```

**The Routes Folder**

```
routes -|        //folder
   pages.js     
   pages -|      // folder
     index.js
```

The pages route

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return [{title: "One", _id: "one"}, {title: "Two", _id: "two"}];
  }
});
```

The pages index route

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return this.modelFor('pages');
  }
});
```

**The Template Folder**

```
templates -|     //folder
   pages.hbs     
   pages -|      // folder
     index.hbs
```

Pages Template

```
<h1>Pages</h1>
<ul>
  {{#each}}
    <li>{{title}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>

{{outlet}}
```

The Index Template

```
<h2>The Index page for Pages</h2>

<ul>
  {{#each}}
    <li>the index page {{title}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Comment: Yup, this is much the same as what I had. I got it figured out now thanks to your help.